# How can I make a div take 100% after another element gets transform'd

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ohgbce6v/

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.game-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  .left {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: lightcoral;

    .topbar-inventory-container {
      width: calc( 100% - 40px );
      margin: 0 20px;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;

      .inventory-hanger-container {
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        justify-content: space-between;

        .vertical-separator {
          margin: 0 40px;
          background: lightgrey;
        }
      }

      .inventory {
        height: 80px;
        background: lightgrey;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }

  .right-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;

    &.closed {
      transform: translateX( $thickness + 400px);
    }

    .hide-shop-btn {
      position: absolute;
      height: 60px;
      width: 40px;
      left: -40px;
      border-top-left-radius: 50%;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
      background: black;
      display: flex;
      align-self: center;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;

      .fa-caret-left {
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px;
      }
    }

    .right {
      width: 400px;
      height: 100%;
      background: darkgray;
    }
  }
}
```

When you click on the little black nub, it should close the menu and the pink spot should take over the rest of the space.
[image]

And this is what it looks like when it's closed:
[image]

How do I make it so the pink spot takes up the rest of the space after the grey area gets transformed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `transform` for this. Instead you can use something like `margin-right: -415px;` to achieve what you want.

When you use `transform` the element is transformed BUT it still takes up space in the DOM as if it wasn't transformed... think of it like a ghost copy of the element.

So update this:

```
.game-container .right-container.closed {
      margin-right: -415px 
}
```

[Update fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohgbce6v/1/)

Can read more about translate [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/#article-header-id-3).

> It’s important to note that an element using transform will not cause
>   other elements to flow around it.

Comment: ahh thanks! Makes sense. I tried altering the 'left' value as well as 'transforming'. Shouldve tried margin